# What is wrong with this code i have written?

Tags: javascript, function

I'm trying to make all of the constants have next to them but nothing is working. 
This is the javascript code here.

```js
function opishConversion(text) {
  var output = "";
  for (var i = 0; i < text.length; i = i + 1) {
    if ((text.charAt[i] !== "a") || (text.charAt[i] !== "A") || (text.charAt[i] !== "e") || (text.charAt[i] !== "E") || (text.charAt[i] !== "i") || (text.charAt[i] !== "I") || (text.charAt[i] !== "o") || (text.charAt[i] !== "O") || (text.charAt[i] !== "u") || (text.charAt[i] !== "U")) {
      output += text.charAt[i] + "op";
    } else {
      output += text.charAt[i];
    }
  }
  return output;
}

var text = prompt("Enter Text To Convert");
alert(opishConversion(text));
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You mean consonants, right?  As in, non-vowel letters?  constants != consonants

Comment: You need to ask a question addressing a specific problem, and avoid questions that are too broad such as "What am I doing wrong?"

Comment: That whole function could be replaced with `text.replace(/([^aeiou])/gi, "$1op")`

Comment: ...your use of `||` should be `&&` instead. Right now you're *always* adding `op` after a letter.

Comment: @squint Give a fish vs teach to fish - fix the syntax error and give it back to them rather than just give them working code that they don't understand

Comment: @Adam: It isn't a syntax error. I'm teaching him that regular patterns can be found using regular expressions.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`charAt` is a native method of the `String` primitive. It should be `charAt(i)` not `charAt[i]`

Comment: The algorithm is wrong as well. The `charAt()` is only part of the issue.

Comment: I have faith that fixing the syntax error that prevented the code from running would allow the OP to debug the rest of it. :)

Comment: It wasn't a syntax error, and the question is asking what's wrong with the code.

Answer (score 4):

string.charAt is a function, not an indexed object.  You need to use parantheses rather than square brackets.

so:

```
text.charAt(i);
```

rather than

```
text.charAt[i];
```

You also need to change your if statement to

```
&&
```

for AND instead of

```
||
```

---

corrected:

```
function opishConversion(text) {
    var output = "";
    for (var i = 0; i < text.length; i = i + 1) {
        if ((text.charAt(i) !== "a") && (text.charAt(i) !== "A") && (text.charAt(i) !== "e") && (text.charAt(i) !== "E") && (text.charAt(i) !== "i") && (text.charAt(i) !== "I") && (text.charAt(i) !== "o") && (text.charAt(i) !== "O") && (text.charAt(i) !== "u") && (text.charAt(i) !== "U")) {
            output += text.charAt(i) + "op";
        } else {
            output += text.charAt(i);  //rather than text.charAt[i];
        }
    }
    return output;
}

alert(opishConversion("aAbBcCdDeEfFgG"))
```

http://jsfiddle.net/8rrd9p9j/2/

Comment: Brackets are still in the `if` statement.

Comment: Good catch; logic was also off.  corrected!

Answer (score 0):

chatAt() is a function so you should not be using square brackets

```
text.charAt(i);
```

Answer (score 0):

All above answers will fix the issue that you have. However, I would also suggest you to simplify the logic by first changing the text to lowercase prior to the for loop.

http://jsfiddle.net/tr9qpqe8/

```
function opishConversion(text) {
  var output = '';
  var text = text.toLowerCase();

  for (var i = 0; i < text.length; i++) {
    if ((text.charAt(i) !== "a") || (text.charAt(i) !== "e") || (text.charAt(i) !== "i") || (text.charAt(i) !== "o") || (text.charAt(i) !== "u")) {
      output += text.charAt(i) + "op";
    } else {
      output += text.charAt(i);
    }
  }

  return output;
}

var text = prompt("Enter Text To Convert");
alert(opishConversion(text));
```